# call a function in another JS file -i have an error: gotoapp is undifined Please advise

Tags: javascript, node.js, function

I'm having an error when calling `goToApp` function. The first page is the creation off the class and functions the second one is the other JS file

please advice

```
    //PO.js- a class I have created



   `class Kibana extends Page {
        constructor() {
            super();
            this._navigator = new KibanaNavigator();
        }

        async goToApp() {
            await this.openApp('DevOps Portal');
            await this.openApp('Kibana');
            // TODO replace with browser.wait();
            await browser.sleep(10000);
            const winHandles = await browser.getAllWindowHandles();
            await browser.switchTo().window(winHandles.pop());
        }

        async openDashboardPage() {
            await this._navigator.navigateTo('Dashboard');
            return new DashboardPage();
        }
    }

    //myFile.js -calling the gotoapp function 

    const Kibana = require('@vos/gallery/ui_page_objects/kibana.po.js');
    const kibana = new Kibana();`enter code here`

    await ui.kibana.goToApp();
```

Comment: Please provide the error you are getting

Answer (score 0):

You have to export your class to use from another file.

Example:

```
class Kibana extends Page { ... }

module.exports.Kibana = Kibana;
```

Answer (score 0):

Any function or class that you want to use in another file, you need to export it. 
like 
In kibana.po.js

```
    export default class Kibana {
     constructor() {
     super();
     // this._navigator = new KibanaNavigator();
   }

   goToApp() {
    console.log("goto application is working");
       }
    }
```

in myfile.js

```
import Kibana from "./kibana.po";
const k = new Kibana();
k.goToApp();
```